# Executing *nix binaries in Python

Tags: python, gnu-screen

I need to run the following command:

```
screen -dmS RealmD top
```

*Essentially invoking GNU screen in the background with the session title 'RealmD' with the top command being run inside screen. The command MUST be invoked this way so there can't be a substitute for screen at this time until the server is re-tooled. (Another project for another time)*

*I've subbed in the top command for the server binary that needs to run. But top is a decent substitute while the code is being debugged for this python module.*

**What I really need is a way to execute screen with the above parameters in Python.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [os.system](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/os.html#os.system):

```
os.system("screen -dmS RealmD top")
```

Then in a separate shell you can have a look at `top` by running `screen -rd RealmD`.

Comment: Because I didn't know about it until now :)

Answer (score 11):

`os.system` is the simplest way, but, for many more possibilities and degrees of freedom, also look at the standard library [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module (unless Stephan202's wonderfully simple use of `os.system` meets all your needs, of course;-).

**Edit** Here's the standard replacement for `os.system()`

```
p = Popen("screen -dmS RealmD top", shell=True)
sts = p.wait()
```

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system